# Multithread Server and Client with sockets in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

I am trying to create for a university project a server / slave / client project.
The server should open 2 ports, one port will be for the connection of the slave and another port for the client.

I have setup 2 threads 1 for the client and another for the slave. The client should sent random numbers to server and server should forward randomly those numbers to slave instances. The slave should check if the current number exist on their list and if it's not available to store it, otherwise they should sent a message to server that the number already exist.

Then I created the client thread which consist of 2 threads, one for sending the numbers to server and another thread to read messages coming from the server.
There is something wrong with the code of the PrintWriter, I cannot make it to send the numbers to server when the code is inside the thread. If I move the code on the main and cancel the thread the messages are being sent without any issue.
What could be the issue for this?

Below is the current code from server (master) and the client.

```
public class Client {
private static final int NUMBERS = 50;
private static final int AMPLITUDE = 100;
private static int masterPort;

public Client(int port) {
    this.masterPort = port;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String serverHostname = "127.0.0.1"; 

    System.out.println("Αναμονή για σύνδεση στον σέρβερ " + serverHostname + " στην πόρτα 30091.");
    Socket echoSocket = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        echoSocket = new Socket(serverHostname, 18889); 
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream())); 
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Δεν μπορεί να πραγματοποιηθεί σύνδεση με τον σέρβερ: " + serverHostname); 
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + serverHostname); 
        System.exit(1);
    }

    ClientOut clientOut = new ClientOut(echoSocket);
    clientOut.start();
    ClientIn clientIn = new ClientIn(in);
    clientIn.start();

    in.close();
    echoSocket.close();
}

public static class ClientOut extends Thread {
    private PrintWriter out;

    public ClientOut(Socket echoSocket) throws IOException {
        this.out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Ο client συνδέθηκε!");
        Random rnd = new Random();
        try {
            for (int i=0; i<NUMBERS; i++) {
                int num = rnd.nextInt(AMPLITUDE);
                System.out.println(num);
                out.println(num);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                out.close();
        }
    }


public static class ClientIn extends Thread {
    private BufferedReader in;

    public ClientIn(BufferedReader in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}

}

public class Master {
private int slavePort;
private int clientPort;
private SlaveThread slaveThread;
private ClientThread clientThread;
private boolean running = false;
public static int slaveConnected; // Slave connection counter

public Master(int slavePort, int clientPort) {
    this.slavePort = slavePort;
    this.clientPort = clientPort;
    this.slaveConnected = 0; 

public void startServer() {
    try {
        this.slaveThread = new SlaveThread(slavePort);
        this.clientThread = new ClientThread(clientPort);
        System.out.println( "Αναμονή για σύνδεση client / slave" );
        slaveThread.start();
        clientThread.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopServer() {
    running = false;
    this.slaveThread.interrupt();
    this.clientThread.interrupt();

}

class SlaveThread extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket slaveSocket;

    SlaveThread(int slavePort) throws IOException {
        this.slaveSocket = new ServerSocket(slavePort);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;
        while (running) {
            try {
                // Call accept() to receive the next connection
                Socket slSocket = slaveSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Δημιουργήθηκε μια νέα σύνδεση Slave");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class ClientThread extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket clientSocket;

    ClientThread(int clientPort) throws IOException {
        this.clientSocket = new ServerSocket(clientPort);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;
        while (running) {
            try {
                Socket clSocket = clientSocket.accept();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clSocket.getInputStream()));
                System.out.println("Δημιουργήθηκε μια νέα σύνδεση Client");

                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine())  != null) {
                    System.out.println("Client: " + inputLine);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Master server = new Master( 30091, 18889);
    server.startServer();
    // Automatically shutdown in 1 minute
    try {
        Thread.sleep( 60000 );
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    server.stopServer();
}
```

Comment: you called 'out.close()' so your socket server closed without issue. Do you want to receive same number after sending random number from client to server?

Comment: The out.close() is outside the for loop, due to many changes I have left it inside the for loop. But this is not causing the problem. In best case I get from the server only the first number. What I have noticed on debugger is the PrintWriter has a flag trouble that is true and I don't know what is causing this change.

Comment: Would you commit and push to the GitHub your code after than, share the address? I think we'd better discuss about code and logic.

Comment: you can check it on https://github.com/mpapado3/Master-Slave-Client/tree/master/src/com/third_sub_ex

Comment: You are closing the socket while the threads are still running. Solution: don't. Close it in the reading thread when end of stream is received.

Comment: @ToroLoco Thanks. I will check it this weekend and If I could find the problem then I will contributing for your code.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution.
The Socket should be created on the Client Thread constructor and not to be passed as reference.
So the client should be

```
public class Client {
private static final int NUMBERS = 50;
private static final int AMPLITUDE = 100;
private static int masterPort;

public Client(int port) {
    this.masterPort = port;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String serverHostname = "127.0.0.1"; //Ορίζουμε την διεύθυνση που είναι ο σέρβερ

    System.out.println("Αναμονή για σύνδεση στον σέρβερ " + serverHostname + " στην πόρτα 30091.");

    ClientOut clientOut = new ClientOut(serverHostname);
    clientOut.start();
    ClientIn clientIn = new ClientIn(serverHostname);
    clientIn.start();
}

public static class ClientOut extends Thread {
    private Socket echoSocket;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    ClientOut(String serverHostname) throws IOException {
        this.echoSocket = new Socket(serverHostname, 18889);
        this.writer = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Ο client συνδέθηκε!");
        Random rnd = new Random();
        try {
            for (int i=0; i<NUMBERS; i++) {
                int num = rnd.nextInt(AMPLITUDE);
                System.out.println(num);
                writer.println(num);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        writer.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This was not the problem. Now you are wastefully creating two sockets per logical conenction.

Comment: I have even tried not to close the connection and only when I created the socket inside the thread I managed to solve it. How it could possibly be solved?

Comment: I had already told you in comments under your question, four days ago.